# Is every single matrix associated to a scalar product diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inner-products, diagonalization, bilinear-form

I'm having trouble answering the question on the title due to the fact that I reach opposite conclusions based on 2 different reasonings. I'd be grateful if you could have a look at them and tell me what's wrong with one (or both) of them:

$\textbf{Reasoning 1}$: The statement in the title is true

Let $V$ be a vector space with some basis $B_V$ and let $G$ be the matrix associated to the scalar product in that given basis. Also, let $G_c$ be the matrix associated to the scalar product in the canonical basis, $B_c$, which we know is diagonal because $<\vec{e}_i, \vec{e}_j> = 0$ if $i \neq j$.

Since the matrixes $G$ and $G_c$ are related according to $G = P^TG_cP$ (and $G_c$ will always exist because the scalar product is always defined for the canonical basis), we know $G$ and $G_c$ are congruent matrixes, which implies they are also equivalent.

By definition, a matrix $A$ is diagonalizable if we can find a matrix $P$ such that $A = P^{-1}DP$, where $D$ is the diagonalized matrix. That is to say, a matrix will be diagonalizable if we can find a diagonal matrix to which it is equivalent.

Since we know our scalar product matrix $G$ will always be congruent with and therefore equivalent to a diagonal matrix $G_c$, then a scalar product matrix can always be diagonalized $\blacksquare$

$\textbf{Reasoning 2}$: The statement in the title is false

We know G will always be a square matrix, and, according to Reasoning 1, we will always be able to diagonalize G. Furthermore, since our basis $B_V$ can be whichever we like as long as it generates the vector space $V$, the scalar product matrix $G$ can take any value.

Since $G$ can be any square matrix and $G$ is always diagonalizable, every square matrix is diagonalizable, which is evidently not true.

Comment: Hint: the scalar product is symmetric, hence the matrix is ... ?

Comment: @Alan The trick is that $G$ can't be **any** square matrix, it has to be symmetric (and positive definite, in fact). The [spectral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem) tells us that every symmetric matrix is diagonalizable.

Comment: Please don't refer to the title of your MSE questions in the body of the question. The body should be self-contained. The title is intended to be a brief description of the question, not part of it. This is a kindness to your readers, and a least once-upon-a-time was vital because some interfaces to MSE didn't render formulas in titles properly.

Comment: it would be nice if you define "scalar product" and "canonical basis".  As written I suspect you are using the dot product and standard basis vectors and the answer to your question regarding similarity transforms highly depends on the field in use, though the field does not matter for congruence transforms [with the exception of characteristic 2].